# Set limits on CPU core utilization in Linux

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-usage, surface

I'm running Linux Mint on a Surface 3 with 4GB of RAM. If all the cores get over 90% utilization the device freezes and needs to be restarted. How can I set limits on the cores? I tried using `nice` and `cgroups` (with `cpu.shares 800`) and `cpulimit` (with `-l 290`), but some programs (e.g. Jetbrains IntelliJ) still hang and force a restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are programs to manage that like cpulimit & or course it ca also be done with cgroups.

The advantage of control groups over cpulimit is that limits are applied to a set of processes.
example :

```
sudo cgcreate -g cpu:/cpulimited
cgset -r cpu.shares=512 cpulimited
```

then use a controled command line over the program you use

```
sudo cgexec -g cpu:cpulimited /path/programthateatressourcesusually
```

if it stille hangs like this & you have a multi code CPU you can try to force process to run on specified core  with `taskset` that comes with linux-utils I think.

if there you have still issues with that program you may contact development team.

Comment: why device freezes?

Comment: sorry but, only you can answer that, without exact knowledge of your setup & of the code you use (the one that freezes your device) Or you have to open a new topic with all detailed description of  all that